# unable to hit the Home-Show controller directly on my site it is going to this custom error page "The requested URL was not found on this server."

Tags: commerce-cloud, demandware

I am unable to hit the Home-Show controller directly on my site it is going to this custom error page "The requested URL was not found on this server."

The Home.js controller is present in my cartridge and even the cartridge is added to the cartridge path. My site is rendering the homepage.isml from Home.js by calling it via Default.js which means Default.js can call Home.js internally but if i want to hit that URL directly it can't be hitten.

Comment: This doesn't sound like it is related to Salesforce which is what this community is about so your question is likely to get closed.

Comment: Aren't you dealing with Salesforce commerce cloud

Comment: In your `Home.js` controller, is the methed `server.get('Show'` present? If you've overridden the `Home.js` controller you should be able to call it accordingly.

Comment: have you added `module.exports = server.exports();` to the controller Home.js?